# Verify sender/source using encyrption with a private key

Tags: cryptography

I have an application that retrieves data from other IoT devices (think in my home, or personal health devices for monitoring). **How can I make sure that the data my application receives comes from the devices I trust?** In other words, I want to make sure that attackers cannot present false data to my application.

The method I had in mind was letting these IoT devices encrypt my data using a private key. If an attacker presents false data without knowledge of the private key, my application won't be able to decrypt it, and hence this indicates that the data is not sent by a trusted source. However, this seems like an unnatural method to do this.

Some notes:

- The information flows according to a pull model, so the application pulls data from the IoT devices. I'm assuming that attackers can pretend to be another device (by copying an IP or MAC address).
- The application is not really implemented. I'm modelling the security requirements for the architecture.

Comment: You can use [TLS with Client Authentication](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-tls-client-auth/). The client certificate for each IoT device should be signed by you at the provisioning time.

Comment: welcome - can you give details about your iot's runtime environment? a general solution to this problem is a form of public-key cryptography where the sender and recipient both hold public keys for the counterparty https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange, and described in excruciating detail here: https://noiseprotocol.org/noise.html#overview-of-handshake-state-machine - a concrete implementation from the *libsodium* library using elliptic curve cryptography is the `crypto_box` https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) to verify the device that your application is communicating with and create a cryptographically secure channel for communications.

But if you only want to verify the data that you're receiving on your application(without encryption), you can [sign the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) with a private key that only the IoT device has, and verify it in your application using IoT device's public key. But not having encrypted channel for communication or rolling your own cryptographic protocol is **not recommended**, so it is better to use protocols that has been around for a while and have had enough time to get audited, and also you should encrypt data to prevent leaking sensitive data or violating user's privacy.

Comment: Please note that the spelling of sensitive is sensitive, other than that it's an ok answer.